# psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation on inserting many-to-many values in association table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Good afternoon.
I have a problem related to appending records to association table using SQLAlchemy and Flask.
It's very simple blog, where "many" Posts can have "many" Tags.

My models:

```
post_tags = Table('post_tags', Base.metadata,
    Column('post_id', Integer, ForeignKey('post.id')),
    Column('tag_nametag', Text, ForeignKey('tag.nametag'))
)

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement='auto')
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'),nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.now().date())
    score = Column(Integer, nullable = False, default = 0)
    title = Column(Text, nullable = False, unique = True)
    body = Column(Text, nullable = False)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary = post_tags,back_populates= 'posts')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.title
    
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement='auto')
    nametag = Column(Text, primary_key = True)
    posts = relationship('Post', secondary = post_tags, back_populates = 'tags')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %r>' % self.nametag
```

I'm using these models with Flask.
Function responsible for adding new posts:

```
@bp.route("/create", methods=("GET", "POST"))
@login_required
def create():
    """Create a new post for the current user."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form["title"]
        body = request.form["body"]
        tags = request.form["tags"].lower()
        new_tags = tags.split(' ')
        error = None

        if not title:
            error = "Title is required."

        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            add_post = Post(title= title,body = body, author_id = g.user.id)
            db.session.add(add_post)
            if tags is not None:
                for i in new_tags:
                    try:
                        add_post.tags.append(Tag(nametag=i))
                        db.session.commit()
                    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
                        print(e)
                        pass
                print('Tags: ', tags)
            return redirect(url_for("blog.index"))
    return render_template("blog/create.html")
```

Everything works fine for inserting completely new tags to PostgreSQL like:
**[(1, 'a'), (1, 'q')]**
Where '1' is an ID of post and 'a' or 'q' are names of tags.

But when I try to add new, second post with exactly the same tags/even one tag which exists in DB I receive such Error:

> (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tag_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (nametag)=(a) already exists.

I understand the reason of this Error - whenever I call **add_post.tags.append(Tag(nametag=i))** app inserts records to association table **post_tags**, but instead checking if there is any tag to refer to in table Tag it just tries to insert new record into Tag table - existing tag name, which generates error.

I'm asking, because I just can't find any good solution to my problem and SQLAlchemy documentation/Stack doesn't present any examples of entering - for example - two different posts with exactly the same tags.

Thank you in advance for any help and pointing out any mistakes I have commited above.

Comment: Have you tried declaring a model class for post_tag association table (for example `PostTag`) and declaring tags field on `Post` to have a relationship to it instead? Then you can write `add_post.tags.append(PostTag(Tag(nametag=i))`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Hi, I haven't tried it, but I'm working on it right now and will definitely try this approach to declare another class model instead of association table and make some kind of "bypass". Thanks for suggestion and I will try to give some feedback on it.